# Creating a function that tests if an array contains something

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

```
openList = Array([1,1], [2,3], [4,5]);
containss = function (input, arrayData, tellID) {
    for (i = 0; i < arrayData.length; i++) {
        if (arrayData[i] == input) {
            if (tellID) {
                return i;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
trace(containss([2,3], openList, true));
```

This code returns false when openList contains 2,3. When I add trace(arrayData[i]), I get 1,1 2,3 4,5 and when I do trace(input) I get 2,3. What is wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing 2 arrays using the equal operator:

> `arrayData[i]==input`

This will always be false, no matter the contents of the arrays. The equal operator in your case tests if `arraydata[i]` is the same object with `input` not if 2 different objects (arrays) have the same content.

Comment: ok, what should I use instead? I tried === but that gives false too.

Comment: The easiest way to do it if the arrays must have the same elements in the same order is array1.toString()==array2.toString()

Comment: If the order is not important and the arrays should only have the same elements in any order you may have to write a custom function for that